# How do I start an intent once a listView item is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

I have a listView which displays ongoing tournaments. My aim is to display the sports that are organized in each tournament (in a separate activity, and also in the form of a listView) once a tournament in the listView is clicked.

I am using firebase. My main concern is how to send the tournamentID of the clicked tournament along with the intent.

This is what my database looks like:

[image]

This is the code:

```
   //tournament_list view to be populated with tournament data
    final ListView tournamentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tournament_list);

    //finding and setting the empty view in the listView when the tournament_list has 0 items
    View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    tournamentListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    final ArrayList<String> tournamentNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final DatabaseReference tournamentRef = mDatabase.child("Tournaments");

    final HashMap<String,String> nameIdMatcher = new HashMap<>();

    tournamentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot tournament : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                TournamentInformation tournamentInformation = new TournamentInformation();
                tournamentInformation.setTournamentName(tournament.getValue(TournamentInformation.class).getTournamentName());
                tournamentNamesList.add(tournamentInformation.getTournamentName());

                nameIdMatcher.put(tournamentInformation.getTournamentName(),tournament.getKey());
                Log.d("Tournament Id:",tournament.getKey());
                Log.d("Main Activity", tournamentInformation.getTournamentName());
            }

            StringAdapter stringAdapter = new StringAdapter(MainActivity.this,tournamentNamesList);
            tournamentListView.setAdapter(stringAdapter);

            tournamentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SportsListActivity.class);
                    String tournamentName = tournamentNamesList.get(position);
                    tournamentId = nameIdMatcher.get(tournamentName);
                    intent.putExtra("tournamentId",tournamentId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });`
```

I read that the putExtra() method will send over data through the intent, but I'm still not sure how to retrieve the tournament ID of the clicked textView. I'm not too sure what the 'id' parameter in the onItemClick() method holds.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your code here

Comment: "I read that the putExtra() method will send over data through the intent, but I'm still not sure how to retrieve the tournament ID of the clicked textView": look here -> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage "I'm not too sure what the 'id' parameter in the onItemClick() method holds" it's an int that represent the position of the clicked list view item. It starts in 0, just like arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get Tournament name from listview click

```
tournamentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

String tournamentName = tournamentNamesList.get(position);
```

Comment: although this works, how can I get the tournament ID? is there a way of getting the tournamentID based on the tournament name?

Comment: I am not seeing anywhere in your code where you saved ur tournament id. Are you saving ur tournament id somewhere outside the code you have shared??

Comment: tournament id can be got by doing this in the for loop - tournament.getKey(). Outside that, I'm not sure there's a way to do it

Comment: @YashChowdhary make your tournamentNamesList custom and along with tournamentName store tournamentId with id, that way it'll be easy for you to get tounamentName and tournamentId whenever you want

Comment: Thanks, that's what I just did. I made a hashmap for the names and IDs @sumit

Comment: @YashChowdhary are you using only hasmap or still using tournamentNamesList along with your hashmap??

Comment: I hash the tournament name with the tournamentId in the for loop. Then, in the onItemClick() method, I get the tournament name using the tournamentNameList, and I use put extra() in which I pass the tournamentId based on the name @sumit

Comment: @YashChowdhary ok you can do that but a much better solution will be to make your tournamentNamesList custom so that you can store both tournamentId and tournamentName together. but anyway do whatever you're comfortable with.